# Adding background color cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I wrote this HTML code

```
 <select value="bgColor" id="selectColor" onchange="changeColor();">
      <option value="selectTheColor">Select color</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
  </select>
```

and this is my JS code, everything works fine except cookie, how do I solve this please?

```
 function changeColor(){
          var selectedColor = document.getElementById("selectColor").value;
          if(selectedColor != "selectTheColor"){
            document.bgColor = selectedColor;
            document.cookie = "color="+selectedColor+";expires=Mon, 5 Mar 2018 02:00:00 UTC";
          }
        }

   window.onload = function(){
        if(document.cookie.length != 0){
          var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
          document.getElementById("selectColor").value = nameValueArray[1];
          document.bgColor=nameValueArray[1];
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the cookie to expire at 2am UTC. It's currently 6:50pm UTC.

Comment: It is still not working,I am updating the question

Comment: @MostafaKhan Define what "not working" means - behavior, errors encountered, etc. - and I'll reopen it.

Comment: After splitting the cookie, nothing works

Comment: Log out the values with `console.log`, then. Bet there's other stuff in the cookie. `console.log(document.cookie)` and `console.log(nameValueArray[1])`.